# C# Regex Validation on server side on dictionary field - .Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-core-mvc

So I have the client side validation in place via jquery. I am trying to achieve the same validation in my application on the server side

The property is of type dictionary and I am struggling to find examples on how to do this. I can't add the regex rule to the property declaration, because each key in the dictionary has a different regex validation needed.

Example, in my controller GET method, I initialize the dictionary:

```
 model.pt_Left = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        { "Key1", "" },
                        { "Key2", "" },
                        { "Key3, "" },
                        { "Key4", "" },
                    };
```

Each of these Keys represent an input field on the view. They each have their own regex validation which I've done in the view.

I'm not sure if this can be implemented server side or not. I can't add the regex to the declaration of the property as that would put the expression on all my 'Keys'

```
[Required]
public Dictionary<string, string> pt_Left { get; set; }
```

An example of the regex I have is `^[0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{2}[\/][0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{2}$`
This is for Key1 only, Key 2-4 each have its own regex validation which is different.

Comment: There's probably 6 ways to do this, but something like using a custom collection instead of Dictionary<string,string> would probably work better for you. PropertyCollection of Properties that have Key, Value, and ValidationExpression. Or Dictionary<string, T> with validation on T. The answers will be subjective on this one.

Comment: Thanks, would you have an example of something I could use? Key, Value and ValidationExpression sounds like something I would need.

Answer (score 0):

Since each regex pattern is unique, that means you **cannot** have a *kitchen sink* one-size fits all pattern.

##### But...

Why not expand your dictionary to have each keys contain the data string and the pattern with logic to process/validate on the object?

Something like

```
public class Data
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public readonly string Pattern { get; set; }
    public IsValid => Regex.IsMatch(Value, Pattern);
    public override string ToString() => Value;
}
```

Then your dictionary instead has this expanded data

```
new Dictionary<string, Data>
   {
        { "Key1", new Data() { Value = "1", Pattern = "^[0-9]..." },
        { "Key2", new Data() { Value = "2...", Pattern = "^\w+..." },
        { "Key3, new Data() { Value = "3...", Pattern = "^[a-d]..." },
        { "Key4", new Data() { Value = "4...", Pattern = "^[0-9]..." },
   };
```

Then you have created an object oriented data class with operations and validation, instead of just a string. Usage of `IsValid` and the override `ToString` should be better than an old string.